# make a single row of divs with horizontal scroll bars

Tags: html, css

Ok so I thought I had this fixed using white-space:no-wrap
it worked in chrome but nothing else.

I have something like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <ul>

        <li>
          <div class="inner">
            <a href="#"><img src="eg1.jpg" /></a>
            <br />
            EG1 lorem ipsum
           </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="inner">
            <a href="#"><img src="eg2.jpg" /></a>
            <br />
            EG2 lorem ipsum
           </div>
        </li>
.
.
.
//etc (multiple li's)

</ul>

</div>
```

excuse the really poor image but this is the efect im aiming for.
[image]

I want a single row of 'items' if they exceed the space then horizontal scroll bars should appear.

hope that makes sense, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Looks like a carousel to me.  Have you looked at the carousel widgets offered by jQuery and YUI?

Comment: @Zoidberb, i was looking at a few caroussls, but couldnt find one that handled content - i.e text and images in this format with minimal fuss

Comment: Check this out http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/carousel/csl_imagentext_source.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Write like this:

```
.outer{
    width:400px;
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.outer li{
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;/*For IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/*For IE7*/
    vertical-align:top;
    width:40px;
    margin-right:20px;
    background:red;
    white-space:normal;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ZrpHv/

Comment: i have a query something similar, In horizontal scroll, there's a content which is cropping. i made an active class which works with my arrow key. when i reach there using arrow key, active class assigned to it which basically giving box-shadow for now,
Now i want to occupy space to see content completely. What css I can use in the `active` class to obtain that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set you div.inner width to something absolute like 64px and the make your `li`s float to either right or left and then set the `overflow-x` property of your parent div to `auto`. check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hamed/95kBF/)

Answer (score 0):

Well I know every good and purist webdeveloper will hate me (and I hate me when I post something like that) but you can simply use table to do that.

this runs in all browsers. Yes, it is not standard, no it is not CSS. But... productivity is sometime better than standard.

You could also used a fixed div width for your container (ul). and use float left position for all your children

Answer (score 0):

You need to put one massive horizontal div inside the parent div with overflow: auto; This will allow the to float left without wrapping to the next line, and it will only scroll when the boundary of the parent div is crossed.