# elements won't stay in a row to be scrolled horizontally

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want a few divs displayed in a row. The container of the divs got a x-scroll attribute and a max-width. But the contained elements don't give want to cooperate.

Here's my code:

```css
.image_container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: auto;
  height: 130px
}
.image {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.first_image {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.img_date {
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 2px;
}
.gallery_container {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(../img/gallery_container_bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  max-height: 150px;
  left: -50px;
  top: 50px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-width: 800px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.1);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery_container">
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="path to img" height="120px" alt="alt" class="first_image image">
    <br>
    <span class="img_date first_image image">Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="path to img" height="120px" alt="alt" class="image">
    <br>
    <span class="img_date image">Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="path to img" height="120px" alt="alt" class="image">
    <br>
    <span class="img_date image">Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="path to img" height="120px" alt="alt" class="image">
    <br>
    <span class="img_date image">Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: [make a single row of divs with horizontal scroll bars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499476/make-a-single-row-of-divs-with-horizontal-scroll-bars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer!

I tried it and it doesn't work for me. After my heartattack I tried some more things and setting the .gallery_container to

```
display: inline-flex;
```

fixed it finally!

Comment: The inline-flex attribute fixed it until I went a little bit deeper. I tried your idea again and it seems like that I made a mistake when I was copying it. Idk where but I'm running your fix atm and it still works!

Answer (score 0):

setting `.image_container` to `display: inline-block` makes images display inline.

```css
.image_container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: auto;
}
.img_date {
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 2px;
}
.gallery_container {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(../img/gallery_container_bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-width: 800px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.1);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery_container">
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" height="120px" alt="alt" class="first_image image">
    <br>
    <span class="img_date first_image image">Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" height="120px" alt="alt" class="image">
    <br>
    <span class="img_date image">Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" height="120px" alt="alt" class="image">
    <br>
    <span class="img_date image">Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" height="120px" alt="alt" class="image">
    <br>
    <span class="img_date image">Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" height="120px" alt="alt" class="image">
    <br>
    <span class="img_date image">Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" height="120px" alt="alt" class="image">
    <br>
    <span class="img_date image">Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" height="120px" alt="alt" class="image">
    <br>
    <span class="img_date image">Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```